# Most efficient way to uppercase/lowercase a string without toUpper/toLower

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, algorithm

What is the best way to uppercase/lowercase a string in .Net without using toUpper/toLower?

Comment: I'll bite: ***Why*** don't you want to use `ToUpper` / `ToLower`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the built-in methods? What about cultural sensitivity?

Comment: Please give more context. What do you want to achieve and why don't you want to use ToUpper/ToLower?

Comment: Nothing, I am just curious...

Comment: @Maxim: StackOverflow is for *"...practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face..."* [(source)](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: It is an actual problem I am facing. I want to know and I dont! :-p

Comment: @Maxim: *-chuckle-* And yet...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
myString.ToLowerInvariant()
```

and

```
myString.ToUpperInvariant()
```

Is what I'd use if ToLower and ToUpper is banned. Also check out [The Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html) for why it's better to use the invariants.

**or**

You could create a function that will loop through the chars, adding to the ASCII values. If you can find out the difference between the lower case and upper case chars ASCII indexes.

Comment: ASCII? *ASCII?* What, have I slipped back to 1987 again? I *hate* when that happens...although the hairstyles are great fun.

Comment: I don't know, I wasn't born until 1988!

Comment: Gaps between i/j and r/s? Does .Net allow implementations to use EBCDIC instead of ASCII?

Answer (score 2):

I tried a few different things before I realized you had 'Most efficient' in your question :)

Anyway, this will work and (on my machine/with limited testing) it appears to perform the same as .ToLower().

```
Dim lower1 As String = StrConv(myStr, VbStrConv.Lowercase)
```

I ran it 100,000 times each way and the results were nearly identical